# I'm having issues with Ostream operator code

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time {
private:
    int hour;
    double minutes; 
public:
    Time(int, double);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Time&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Time&);
    friend bool operator ==(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator >(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator <(const Time&, const Time&);
    friend bool operator <=(const Time&, const Time&);
    Time& operator=(const Time& t) {
        if (this != &t) {
            hour = t.hour;
            minutes = t.minutes;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Time operator++() {
        ++hour;
        ++minutes;
        return *this;
    }
    
    Time operator--() {
        --hour;
        --minutes;
        return *this;
    }

};

Time::Time(int h, double min) {
    hour = h;
    minutes = min; 
}

ostream &operator <<(ostream &time, const Time &h) {
    time << "The Time of the day is: ";
    time << h.hour << ":" << h.minutes << endl;
    cout << endl;
    //time << "After inputting your time I'm going to round up to the nearest hour: " << endl;
    
    return time;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& time, Time& m) {
    cout << "Please enter the hour: ";
    cin >> m.hour;
    cout << "Please enter the minute: ";
    cin >> m.minutes;
    cout << endl;
    return time;
}

bool operator == (const Time& t, const Time& ts) {
    return ((t.hour == ts.hour) && (t.minutes == ts.minutes));
}

bool operator >(const Time& t, const Time& ts) {
    if (t.hour > 24) {
        if (ts.minutes > 60) {
            return (t.hour);
        }
        return(ts.minutes);
    }
}

bool operator <(const Time& t, const Time& ts) {
    if (t.hour < 5) {
        if (t.hour == ts.hour) {
            return (t.hour == ts.hour);
        }
        return (t.hour > 5);
    }
}



int main()
{
    Time time(0, 0);
    Time time2(0, 0);
    cout << "Please enter Military time between 1:00 - 24:00: " << endl;
    cin >> time;
    cout << time;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the Military time for person 2: " << endl;
    cin >> time2;
    cout << time2;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After entering the times for two people I'll be comparing Whether or not both of these times are the same or different: " << endl;
    cout << endl;
    if (time == time2) {
        cout << "The Time is the same" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "These times aren't the same" << time;
    }

   



    return 0;
}
```

The problem with my code right now is that after running and executing my code it'll run the first cout statement that I have in the ostream operator code. I don't understand because the if-statement should only say whether or not the times are the same based on the minute and the hour. I need help in order to figure out why the code is executing twice.

Comment: What is the input you're supplying? What is the output you expect? What is the actual output? This seems to make sense: https://ideone.com/0t5K75

Comment: operator> and operator< don't return anything in every path.  Your compiler should have warned you about that.  Also saying `return (t.hour);` or ` return(ts.minutes);` from inside a function that has a bool return type doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Unrelated: The custom assignment operator is unnecessary. [The Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) suggests that if the class has no m members that require special handling, and `double` and `int` are about as simple as it gets, the copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor should be left out or defaulted. The operator looks correct, but why risk it? Code you don't write has no bugs.

Comment: It's also not good practice to have an `operator>>()` that writes to any stream, or that reads from a completely different stream than the supplied argument.  Your `operator>>()` does both.

Comment: You might want to re-write this. Good questions tend to start with the question, not with code (c.f. [ask]). Code is better thought of as illustration or clarification, rather than as the core of a question. This perspective can help avoid ambiguities such as referring to "the" if-statement when there are five in your code, none of which are in an operator that could be called "the ostream operator". Furthermore, this view is conducive to focusing your code on the specific issue, c.f. [mre] (why are so many class details needed to demonstrate "the ostream operator"?).

Comment: I appreciate the feedback everybody, I was able to figure it out, due to the fact that I had written a cout statement that would always output the time of the day after time was used in the main function. which meant all I had to do was remove those two lines of code inside of my output method and it worked like a charm. As the reason for every single overload for certain operators is due to the nature of my assignment.